# ERROR: operator does not exist with custom domain

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, where-clause

I have declarations in my schema for Postgres 12 database:

```sql
CREATE TYPE something_e AS ENUM('OPEN', 'CLOSE');
CREATE DOMAIN something_t AS something_e NOT NULL DEFAULT 'OPEN';
CREATE TABLE xxx (
...
something something_t,
...
);
```

And it seems that INSERTs work fine. But the select - does not:

```sql
INSERT INTO yyy (...) VALUES (..., (SELECT ID FROM xxx WHERE ... AND something='OPEN'));
```

And here I get an error:

> "ERROR:  operator does not exist: something_t = unknown".

I tried to cast a type to `something_e`, to `something_t` with `::` but without any success. I even got an error like "operator does not exist: something_t = something_t" ! My initial idea was to reduce repeating of a code, so to introduce this `something_t` new domain based on the enum `something_e`, but how to select now using such a criteria? INSERT's seems cast 'OPEN' strings to `something_t` automatically... What is the right syntax for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compare a string to a value of a custom type directly:

```
select * from xxx where something = 'OPEN';
-- ERROR: operator does not exist: something_t = unknown
```

You can't use the equality operator on a custom type:

```
select * from xxx where something = 'OPEN'::something_t;
-- ERROR: operator does not exist: something_t = something_t
```

You *can*, however, cast the type value to a string, then compare:

```
select * from xxx where something::text = 'OPEN'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e34dc69ed3655eec752c85d59d3f2a4c)**

Comment: OK, it helps, but what is the canonical way to work with domains with enums as underlying type? Is the cast lightweight enough?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a type cast, so that [PostgreSQL's type resolution rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html) can find the suitable operator.

That can either be an explicit cast:

```
... WHERE CAST(something AS text) = 'OPEN'
```

or you create an implicit type cast:

```
CREATE CAST (something_e AS text) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```

Then you can use your query without an explicit cast.